# Export Settings in VS2015 without license

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know a way to export settings in VS2015 without a license?

My company had an msdn license which allowed me to use the Enterprise version, the new msdn license they have only allows VS professional.  So when I open VS now I get an error saying that I need to renew my license.  As far as I can tell from my web searches, there is no way to downgrade VS2015.  The only option is to uninstall enterprise and re-install professional.  However I can't access any of the menus in Visual Studio to export all my settings.

Answer (score -1):

In the default Instalation from Visual Studio, it saves the current settings on the Documents folder/Visual Studio (Year)/Setting/.../CurrentSettings.vssettings